# How to version gitea configuration?

Tags: git, gitea

I'm running a dockerized Gitea. I'd like to store the configuration file (`app.ini`) in a git repo, but it contains a few inappropriate values like encryption secrets. How can I store the config in git, without exposing the secrets?

Comment: Put in the repository a sample `app.ini` (name it `app.sample.ini`) and add `app.ini` to `.gitignore`. Put good default values in `app.sample.ini` and empty entries for the sensitive properties (usernames, passwords etc) and also for the properties that might be different on different computers (paths f.e.). Describe in the documentation (and in `app.sample.ini`) how to create `app.ini` from `app.sample.ini` and what values need to be set in it.